# Занести в массив значения активных чекбоксов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Нужно занести в массив program чекбоксы checked.

```
var program = [];
 for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  $('#pre_content5').append('<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name = "sam" value = "'+i+'"/>');
}
```

Знаю, что с помощью jQuery можно отобрать все чекед

```
$('input:checkbox:checked')
```

Как именно значения чекбоксов заполнить в массив? Н-р при нажатии на кнопку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

есть такая штука .map():

```
var arr=$('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {return this.value;}).get();
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/P7VNj/)

[дока](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE.** Как заметил [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto), действительно лучше использовать [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) в сочетании с событием [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/). Должно получиться что-то вроде такого.

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function (ev) {
    program = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
});
```

---

Если под "значением" имеется ввиду поле `value`, то можно как-то так.

```
var program = [];

function scanChecboxes() {
    program = [];

    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
        program.push($(this).val());
    });
}
```

И вызывать эту функцию при изменении состояния одного из чекбоксов. Надёжнее всего событие `mousedown`.

```
$('input:checkbox').each(function () {
    $(this).mousedown(scanCheckboxes);
});
```

Comment: вторая часть вашего ответа вызывает сомнения. во первых, тут целесообразно использовать on, во вторых, mousedown плохое событие для чекбоксов

Comment: @eicto Согласен. Обновил свой ответ.

Comment: @khaos, я про события, не вижу обновления.